# Insert selection into range

Tags: sql, postgresql, range, plpgsql

Im trying to insert a selection of 2 fields into a int4range data type.

lets say i have a table references like below:

```
  r_ref | r_nref
10(char),20(char)
30(char),40(char)
```

my range_test table would look like:

```
add_range
[10,20)
[30,40)
```

This was the way i thought it would work, but seems not. Tried a few more variances but so far no sucess

```
insert into range_test (add_range)
select ((r_ref)::char,r_nref)::char)
from references

ERROR:  column "add_range" is of type int4range but expression is of type record
LINE 2: select (r_ref,r_nref)
```

Comment: [Constructing Ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Abelisto guidance pointing to documentation got it working,
Posting the answer for future questions

[Constructing Ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT)

```
insert into range_test (add_range)
select int4range(r_ref::int,r_nref::int,'[)')
from references
```

Comment: According to your question, it should be `int4range(r_ref::int,r_nref::int,'[)')` or just `int4range(r_ref::int,r_nref::int)`...